# Converting decimals into binaries of only two digits: 1 and 2

Tags: algorithm, binary, converters

I have a problem with an exercise form my uni book. Here it is:

> We are interested in a binary system representing positive integers with only two digits: 1 and 2 (no zeroes!). The subsequent positions correspond to the successive powers of the two, as in the usual binary notation: at the k-th position there is a digit whose value is multiplied by 2^k for k = 0, 1, 2... . In this system - as there are no leading zeros - in addition to formerly mentioned number representation, we use a value that specifies the number of selected digits, let's call it c. Each number is therefore represented by a pair (a, c), where a is a finite sequence of 1 and 2, and c determines the length of that sequence. For example, the pair (12, 3) represents the number 4, and the pair (221, 3) represents the number 13. Write a function which, for a positive number x, determines the representation of its value in the system in question and passes it through the parameter y. Let's agree that in case x is not positive, the value of field c should be 0.

I found that I can easly convert decimal input to binary system and then convert binary to the system mentioned in the exercise. Startng from right I need to remove zeros by converting higher digit 1 into lower digit 2.

E.g.: Decimal = 21. Binary = 10101. The system form the exercise = 101**0**1 -> 10**02**1 ; 10**0**21 -> **02**021 -> 0**12**21

However, there is probably more efective solution that would convert decimal directly to the system from the exercise. I'd appreciate your help in finding the algorithmic path of thinking. I would then code it by myself to make sure I understand it.

It is my first post on the forum and english is not my native language. I am sorry if I did not express myself clear enough.

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let *n* be the number that we're trying to represent. The number *c* has to satisfy

> 2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + … + 2<sup>*c*−1</sup> = 2<sup>*c*</sup> − 1 ≤ *n* ≤ 2<sup>*c*+1</sup> - 2 = 2 (2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + … + 2<sup>*c*−1</sup>).

By inspection, these ranges partition the natural numbers, so the unique solution is *c* = ⌊log<sub>2</sub> (*n*+1)⌋. The floor-log often can be computed with a single instruction, or you can use a [bit-twiddling hack](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html).

Once we know *c*, we just have to find the usual binary representation of *n* − (2<sup>0</sup> + 2<sup>1</sup> + … + 2<sup>*c*−1</sup>) = *n* − (2<sup>c</sup> − 1) and add one to each digit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think that it's a great solution. I just don't understand one point. "By inspection, these ranges partition the natural numbers, so the unique solution is c = ⌊log2 (n+1)⌋." Could you explain that that a bit further? I mean - how do you know that c = ⌊log2 (n+1)⌋?

Comment: @thefool If we add one to both sides, we get 2^c ≤ n ≤ 2^(c+1) - 1, or 2^c ≤ n < 2^(c+1). Take log2 of both sides and get c ≤ log2(n) < c+1. Since c is an integer, it works out to be the definition of floor(log2(n)).